# Facebook parses the wrong thumbnail for my wordpress posts

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am running a Wordpress site, with the WordPress Facebook Open Graph protocol plugin installed.

Facebook linter and RSSGraffiti both show only the image assigned with the og:image meta-data.

However, when a person posts the link on their wall or clicks the share button on my website, Facebook decides to show only the first img found in my website's html, ignoring the proper one.

Any idea on how to resolve this matter?

Thank you in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possibly a size issue? For example, [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) indicates that the image must be at least 200px by 200px. It would help if you could post the URL of your website that isn't working.

Comment: I missed that one, the thumbnail indeed should meet the minimum requirement of 200 pixels height AND width. Thank you very much sir.